# How do you use a JavaScript module with AppleScript in a browser?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, module, safari, applescript

Usually when you script a browser using AppleScript (AS) and want to send a JavaScript (JS) snippet to be executed you just send the JS as text to the browser using something like `do/execute JavaScript ("alert 'hello world'");` but if you have JS module, such as this https://gist.github.com/uangsl/63978e459df3037cc8ec0d808d8b7df3 - how do use it/call its methods from AS?

(I am not sure I am even asking the right question here. Maybe this module isn't even supposed to be executed from within a browser but from an "interpreter" or shell, similar to how you execute a shellscript? Anyway, the question remains - how do you execute this module/its methods from AS?)